# Create Azure Function to call the Yammer API and use it in Flow

Tags: azure, power-automate, yammer

I'm aware that in Microsoft Flow you can use the existing Yammer connector to login to Yammer and send messages. I know that sending praise is not currently supported but it is possible by calling the REST API. Therefore I created an Azure Function to do that and set up a connector so I could call it from Flow. This works if I provide the Azure Function with a bearer token. But is it possible to some how login to Yammer, obtain a token and pass it to the function during the Flow creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know enough about Microsoft Azure functions to answer that part of the question. However, I know that if you have the access token for a verified admin user in a Yammer network, you can use obtain the access token of any other user in the Yammer network and impersonate them (https://developer.yammer.com/docs/impersonation). Perhaps this will help.